# Is my guitar's neck supposed to be angled upwards?

Tags: guitar, ibanez

[image]My Ibanez Artcore's strings are buzzing towards the top of the neck (1st fret). I have tried raising the action but the strings are very high off the fret towards the 20th fret and I still get some buzzing. Do I need to adjust the truss rod to fix this or is the neck tilted upward normal?[image] I'm replacing the string later today.

[image: Replacing string later today]

Comment: We can't see the neck.

Comment: I'm referring to the portion of the neck in the photo. In the picture, the neck is at an upwards angle compared to the body of the guitar.

Comment: That definitely looks broken to me, like the neck is breaking off from the body. And I can't see anything similar on photos of other Artcores.

Comment: Unless we can see the entire structure, we should avoid making wild assumptions. If the action can lift far enough to almost match that rather excessive neck angle, it can't be *that* far out of tolerance.

Comment: That would be a normal neck angle for a Les Paul, but not for a fender strat. Can you post a shot looking from the nut along the neck to the bridge?

Comment: @BrianTowers That post makes me think that the neck position is ok so I'm not sure how else to alleviate the buzzing strings.

Comment: @Tetsujin The action looks like it can reach that far. So when the action is extended all the way, there is less buzzing but it still produces buzzing sometimes. I'll post more pictures now.

Comment: Without all strings in place, there isn’t proper tension on the neck to assess your setup. You should have all six strings tuned to pitch, then look at neck angle, relief, etc., then make any necessary adjustments.

Comment: @wabisabied The original issue was diagnosed with all six strings tuned. As I was adjusting the action, some of the string popped so basically the neck position hasn't changed visibly (the angle is still the same).

Comment: @Dan Got it. You probably already know then to make your truss rod adjustments with all six strings tuned to pitch. Good luck.

Comment: @wabisabied Thanks, I'll let you know if it makes a difference with the buzzing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the truss rod could be the solution. If you add a little relief, that would tend to scoop the 2nd fret a little lower w.r.t the string path from the first fret to the saddle. But also check that the frets are level and the nut height is ok. It could be a high 2nd fret or a low nut.

The neck angle isn't necessarily an issue unless you're up against the limits of less extreme adjustments.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just need to figure out where to adjust the truss rod. You wouldn't happen to know where to check for the place to insert the allen wrench on an Ibanez Artcore would you?

Comment: Is there a little cover plate on the headstock?

Comment: Ah yes I see it. You recommend loosening the truss right? Lefty loosey?

Comment: That should be right. I'd do a very slight adjustment -- no more than 1/4 turn -- and then check. Lay a straightedge across the fretboard.

Comment: Just made the adjustment and used a straightedge and it looks pretty flat. Should there be a downwards bend or is flat ok?

Comment: Do you have the strings on? To really check, need to string it and tune up and measure then. And actually check the buzzing issue then too. You don't need to remove the strings if it needs more adjustment at that point, just loosen them a little.

Comment: Got it, picking up more strings now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I meant to say a left turn should be *correct*. I hope my meaning wasn't confusing. Saying *right* was a poor word choice on my part.